# golang/mgo: leave out empty fields from insert

Tags: go, bson, mgo

For some reason `mgo` inserts the empty struct into the db as null value even though I've set omitempty option.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "encoding/json"
)

type A struct {
    A bool
}

type B struct {
    X       int `json:"x,omitempty" bson:"x,omitempty"`
    SomeA   *A `json:"a,omitempty" bson:"a,omitempty"`
}

func main() {
    b := B{}
    b.X = 123

    if buf, err := json.MarshalIndent(&b, "", " "); err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    } else {
        fmt.Println(string(buf))
    }
}
```

The json encoder leaves out the `SomeA` property but in the database it's there as `"a" : null`.
Am I doing something wrong, or it's simply not possible to do it this way?

Comment: Can you show us how you're inserting it into mongo?

Comment: The value should be skipped: http://bazaar.launchpad.net/+branch/mgo/v2/view/head:/bson/encode.go#L165

Comment: I have an additional field in struct A: Id bson.ObjectId `bson:"_id"` and I simply call the Insert function:
err = db.Mongo.C("collection").Insert(&b)

Comment: Oh god. It's working now. Problem was I had tabs between the json and bson encoder options not just a single space. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Andrew - can you post that as an answer and accept it to help others who have the same problem, please.

Comment: Yeah, done it, sorry. Can't accept my own answer though.

Answer (score 8):

Yeah, so problem was having tabs between the json and bson encoder options, that's why omitempty didn't work. So this is **wrong**:

```
SomeA   *A `json:"a,omitempty"         bson:"a,omitempty"`
```

Instead just have a single space and it's all **good**:

```
SomeA   *A `json:"a,omitempty" bson:"a,omitempty"`
```